# Passing ampersand to ajax with jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have this ajax call

```
 function addNewRemarksToDataBase(argRemark) {
            if (argRemark != '') {
                // if not blank
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../AutoComplete.asmx/AddNewRemarks',
                    type: 'POST',
                    timeout: 2000,
                    datatype: 'xml',
                    cache: false,
                    data: 'argRemarks=' + argRemark,
                    success: function (response) {
                        // update the field that is source of remarks
                        updateRemarksSource();
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

The method is defined as

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddNewRemarks(string argRemarks)
{
    BAL.BalFactory.Instance.BAL_Comments.SaveRemarks(argRemarks, Globals.BranchID);
}
```

The problem is if a user enters something like `long & elegant` or something like `smart & beautiful`, something that contains `&`, I only get the first part before `&`, `long` (in the first case), `smart` (in the second one) (also notice the whitespace!)

I read in [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that one should set **`processData`** to false, because it is something used for querystring or something. I added the

```
processData: false
```

but I am still getting the term before the `&`. I don't want to use `encodeURIComponent` because it will turn the `&` to `amp;` (or something like that). What I need is the full value `long & elegant`, `smart & beautiful` that will be saved to the database. How can I do this?

***EDIT*** Doing `{ argRemarks: argRemark }` doesn't helps! The function doesn't event gets called. Running it with firebug, and setting breakpoint in error function, I got this

```
[Exception... "Component does not have requested interface"  nsresult: "0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:49903/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js :: .send :: line 2"  data: no]"
```

***UPDATE 2 :***
Doing

```
data: 'argRemarks=' + encodeURIComponent(argRemark)
```

did the trick. But can anyone help me understand how does this works? I thought it would convert `&` to `&amp;` but it didn't? The parameter I am receiving to the method now is just what I wanted, **`long & elegant`, `smart & beautiful`**, doesn't `encodeURIComponent()` converts special characters?

Comment: Re update 2: `&` to `&amp;` is HTML entity encoding, which is totally unrelated; url encoding is `&` to `%26`. In both cases though the receiver decodes the data before processing it, the encoding just serves to *get the data to pass unharmed through an "unfriendly" channel*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *do* need to encode the `argRemark`. The easiest way to do this is to let jQuery do the job for you:

```
data: { argRemarks: argRemark }
```

This is different than `data: 'argRemarks=' + argRemark` in that by passing in an object, jQuery assumes that it needs to URL-encode the values of the properties on that object -- while if passing in a string, you are expected to have properly encoded it beforehand.

Comment: And if you don't want to let jQuery do it for you, just use `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: @Jon:
This doesn't works! Doing this, the method wasn't even called (breakpoint wasn't hit). Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: @Razort4x: Since this has nothing at all to do with methods being called, perhaps a syntax error? Missing comma at the end of the line, which you need but I didn't use above?

Comment: @Jon:
Nope. I rechecked the syntax, could it be that since now I am passing an object, as seen in firebug `Object { argRemarks="long & long,other & first"}`, does that means I have to change the way my method is accepting the argument?

Comment: @Razort4x: No. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is pretty clear, and this is a very common piece of functionality that scores of devs use every day. It has to be something with your particular setup or some other code you run.

Answer (score 3):

You have to URL-encode the string first:

```
data: 'argRemarks=' + encodeURIComponent(argRemark)
```